# математики и программисты нужна помощь в программе на паскале!

Tags: математика, pascal, геометрия

Есть задача:

> С клавиатуры вводится число a и число b ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4} (именно в этом порядке). Рассмотрим равнобедренный прямо-
> угольный треугольник. Если b = 1, то a – периметр; если b = 2, то a – биссектриса, опущенная на катет; если b = 3, то a – площадь вписанной окружности, если b = 4, то a – катет. Выведите на экран периметр, биссектрису, опущенную на
> катет, площадь вписанной окружности и катет треугольника.**

Код программы к задаче:

```
var  
  a,b:integer;  
  c:real;  
begin  
read(a, b);  
case b of
  1: c := a / (2 + sqrt(2));
  2: c := a * cos(pi / 8); 
  3: c := sqrt(a / pi) / (1 - 1 / sqrt(2)); 
  4: c := a
end;
writeln('Катет: ', c);
writeln('Периметр: ', c * (2 + sqrt(2)));
writeln('Площадь: ', pi * sqr(c * (1 - 1 / sqrt(2))));
writeln('Биссектриса: ', c / cos(pi / 8));
end.
```

В задаче "a" выступает как катет ?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

В задаче `a` выступает как периметр, или биссектриса, опущенная на катет, или площадь вписанной окружности, или катет в зависимости от значения `b`.

После того, как `a` и `b` введены, рассчитывается катет `c`, а потом и все остальные требуемые величины на основании величины `c`.

Я бы поменял тип `a` на `real`.

В равнобедренном прямоугольном треугольнике все вышеперечисленные величины однозначно зависят друг от друга, поэтому зная одну величину, можно вычислить все остальные.

Чтобы не использовать всю комбинацию зависимостей, в качестве промежуточной величины используется катет, от которого вычисляется всё остальное.

Таким образом, на первом этапе программы (case) в зависимости от значения `b` вычисляется катет `c`. То есть если `b` = 1, то `a` - это периметр, и `c` вычисляется по формуле зависимости длины катета от периметра; если `b` = 2, то `a` - это биссектриса, и `c` вычисляется по формуле зависимости длины катета от биссектрисы.

На втором этапе программы после `writeln('Катет: ', c)` вычисляются и одновременно выводятся все остальные величины.

Comment: к примеру **a = 25** **b = 1**, получается программа вывела периметр = 25, но как программа его вывела ?

Comment: @Palindrom Умножили и разделили на `(2 + sqrt(2))`